# actionlistener not working primefaces

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

I have a problem with hibernate and primefaces, my code is as follows:

empleadoDao:

```
public interface empleadoDao {
    public List<Tbempleado> mostrarempleado();
    public void nuevoEmpleado (Tbempleado tbempleado);

    //Metodos para poblar los SelectOneMenu
    public List<Tbpais> listarPaises();
    public List<Tbdepartamento> listarDepartamentos(Tbempleado empleado);
}
```

empleadoDaoImp:

```
public class empleadoDaoImp implements empleadoDao{
    @Override
    public void nuevoEmpleado(Tbempleado tbempleado){
        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(tbempleado);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("error"+ex.getMessage());
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally{
            if(session!=null){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

empleadoBean:
public class empleadoBean implements Serializable

```
    public void nuevoEmpleado() {
        empleadoDao eDao = new empleadoDaoImp();
        eDao.nuevoEmpleado(empleado);
        empleado = new Tbempleado();
    }
```

My form index.xhtml of button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{empleadoBean.nuevoEmpleado()}" />
```

Comment: please share error message.

Comment: Do you have an error or the behaviour is not as you expected?

Comment: does not give me error message, does nothing does not save...

Comment: So your actionListener is not invoked? Have you debugged the issue? Does your browser console show any error message?

Comment: So it works when using a non-primefaces plain jsf `h:commandButton`?

Comment: yes and no results

Comment: In my code the empleadoBean thepublic class is implements serializable,I do not know if it has to do with that I do not work the method of saving.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Comment: Thanks to all who helped, each one of his contributions was very valuable, in the end I had bad my Bean, had declares in annotation @ManagedBean, was curious, took it and walked, just as I learned in the process another way to do it the POJOS in EJB 3 Annotation, not mapped by XML, Thanks to all ...